# Using the public hostname in a personal public DNS server

Tags: dns, ip, domain, hostname

### Scenario

I have a small website on a Windows 10 Pro N pc with (e.g.) public ip: `123.456.78`
If I type in that ip from anywhere the website opens fine.

Now I also bought 2 domains name e.g. `www.somewebsiteOne.com` and `www.somewebsiteTwo.org` at 2 different domain sellers. And depend on a dns service which forwards `www.somewebsiteTwo.ddns.net` to `123.456.78`. In the domain sellers, I can then forward `www.somewebsiteTwo.org` to `www.somewebsiteTwo.ddns.net`. My intention is to replace the dependency on the DNS server with my self-hosted opensource DNS server using Technitium.

To verify my own DNS server is working I:

1. Open powershell on a different computer on a different network.
2. enter: nslookup www.somewebsiteTwo.org 123.456.78
3. Which indeed returns the ip adress 123.456.78

### Problem

Now if I try to enter the ip adress of that DNS server in either of the 2 domain sellers, I am required to enter:

- Hostname
- Ip adress

Where for the hostname I can enter something like `www.somewebsiteTwo.ddns.net`(which is a dns server that forwards `www.somewebsiteTwo.org` to `123.456.78`  and for the ip adress `123.456.78`.  After calling with one of the two, I was explained they use the hostname and not the IP adress to find my personal public DNS server, not the IP adress.

This essentially means that I need a dns server to forward some hostname for my personal public dns server to the ip adress of my dns server. Which defeats my intentions. Therefore I have the following:

### Question

How can I determine and use a functioning hostname that refers to my personal public dns server at `123.456.78`?

### Attempts

- I tried to enter the hostname of my pc, e.g. what's returned in cmd at command `hostname`. But that is not considered a valid hostname.
- I tried to enter `123.456.78` but that is not considered a valid hostname.
- I tried to enter `http://123.456.78/` but it does not work.
- The ip-adresses don't work as a hostname referring to a DNS server because:

> The hostname to use for a DNS server and when registering and using a DNS (sub-) domain must be a valid fully qualified DNS hostname such
>   as for instance ns1.example.com. or
>   customer-5363.dsl-users.isp.example.net . The protocol does not allow
>   an IP-address. If you want to use a DNS record such as ns1.example.com
>   to register the domain example.com your registrar will need to set up
>   the correct glue record first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After calling with one of the two, I was explained they use the hostname and not the IP adress to find my personal public DNS server, not the IP adress.
>
> This essentially means that I need a dns server to forward some hostname for my personal public dns server to the ip adress of my dns server. Which defeats my intentions.

That's not entirely correct.

It is true that NS records, used for domain delegations, *only* take hostnames and not raw addresses.

However, you're actually allowed to specify a hostname that is under your own domain, and that's why there are IP address fields alongside: they let you *define* the hostname and use it at the same time. This is actually what the support message is referring to when they mention "glue records", which allow this kind of 'loop'.

(Note that you're supposed to add exactly the same hostname definitions in your own DNS server as well – the glue records at the registrar are considered a copy, and the ones on your server the authoritative version.)

---

For example, when you enter the nameserver `ns1.somewebsite.com`, the registrar publishes this DNS record:

```
somewebsite.com. NS ns1.somewebsite.com.
```

Since the nameserver's hostname is under the domain that it's hosting, this clearly wouldn't work as is as it would create a loop. So you *also* need to enter the server's IP address in the corresponding field, and that allows the registrar to publish a second DNS record (the "glue" record):

```
somewebsite.com. NS ns1.somewebsite.com.
ns1.somewebsite.com. A 12.34.56.78
```

Whenever a resolver tries to query the nameservers for your domain, their IP addresses from glue records will always be attached to the same response, avoiding the loop issue.

Comment: "the registrar publishes this DNS record:"  it is the registry that publishes this, in the parent zone. Registrars just transmit, typically over EPP, requests for changes to the registry, who manages the DNS. Also , please use guidance from RFC2606 when obfuscating names. And RFC 5737 for IP addresses.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks to your answer I was able to succesfully implement a personal DNS server! I included the explicit settings and steps for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

In my question, the hostname was just the an arbitrary set of characters, usually `ns1` and `ns2` followed by `<website without the http://www.>`
e.g. if your website is `swag.org` you can create `ns1.swag.org` in your own dns server settings and then enter the "hostname" `ns1.swag.org` in your registar. You (usually) need 2 dns servers so, so you make another "hostname" with `ns2.swag.org` and also enter that. Then at the IP you just enter the public ip adress of your pc that hosts the dns server (which you also entered at the `ns1.swag.org` entry in the Technitium/DNS settings.

Below is an example of how to do this all with pictures.

### Verified settings to host your own dns server:

1. In short your put these settings in your technitium settings panel, (replace the `your ip` with the public ip adress of your computer/host/the device you host your website on. (The `A` `ns1.<yourwebsite>` ` is a glue record that tells the computer that links people to your website , "when you are looking for this hostname/website, you can look at this ip to find the hostname/website", (But then it would get in an infinte loop so you tell it ok stop here, you found the website at this ip.)

[image: The DNS settings on your pc in your Technitium host.]

2. Then create the custom dns record in your domain registrar, this is done different for every domain seller. This is the example for namecheap. In short you want to type your your dns server hostname (if you put `ns1.<yourwebsite adres>` in the technitium enter that, together with the public ip adress of your computer.

[image: Entering your dns server in your registrar]

3. You can inspect your dns server/glue record to ip is entered correctly by searching: `ns1` or `ns2` (if you entered `ns1.<yourwebsite>`:

[image: Verify your dns server(s) are entered correctly]

4. Don't forget to also select your own custom dns in the website settings, otherwise you have configured everything correctly in your local dns server, and told the registrar hey at custom dns, look at this ip for my own dns server, but then in the end the registrar still looks in its own default dns server, (where it won't find your ip, you need to pay for that).

[image: Select your personal/custom dns server in your registrar settings]

## Notes

1. These settings do not yet allow for `https://www.yourwebsite.something`. For that you need an ssl certificate, you can get one for free at openssl and Technitium indeed supports https. However I have not yet implemented that.
2. A more detailed and elaborate set of instructions is found on: https://github.com/a-t-0/DnsServer along with the opensource DNS server Technitium, made by someone else, I just forked it and added instructions.